# How can I fix IndexError: list index out of range in Python?

Tags: python, arrays

I wrote a code for getting multiply of two arrays but when I try to get the values for 2. array I am getting an error after 1. element.

The error is: vc = [a_list[i] * b_list[i] for i in range(len(a_list))]
IndexError: list index out of range

Here is the code:

```
a_list = []
b_list = []
count = 0

while count != -1:
    n = int(input("1. array size : "))
    print("1. array elements")
    for i in range(0, n):
        ele = int(input())
        a_list.append(ele)
        print(a_list)
    m = int(input("2. array size : "))
    if n != m:
        print("create arrays at the same size")
        a_list.clear()
        count += 1
    else:
        print("2. array elements:")
        for i in range(0, n):
            elee = int(input())
            b_list.append(elee)
            print(b_list)
            vc = [a_list[i] * b_list[i] for i in range(len(a_list))]
            print("Last List: " + str(vc))
        count+= 1
```

Comment: Because `b_list` isn't as long as `a_list`…?!

Comment: But I got them at the same size@deceze

Comment: How have you confirmed that?

Comment: Maybe I do not understand the main issue.I got  each of them as 3 elements array.@deceze

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are indentations looks to be incorrect. Because `b_list` will only have 1 element when you come to `vc = [a_list[i] * b_list[i] for i in range(len(a_list))]` the first time.

`vc = [a_list[i] * b_list[i] for i in range(len(a_list))]` and the `print("Last List: " + str(vc))` should not be inside the `for i in range(0, n):` loop. This should work:

```
    else:
        print("2. array elements:")
        for i in range(0, n):
            elee = int(input())
            b_list.append(elee)
            print(b_list)
        vc = [a_list[i] * b_list[i] for i in range(len(a_list))]
        print("Last List: " + str(vc))
        count+= 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.It worked.I am appreciate it.@Sefan